# Gap between Navigation bar and view controller content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am about create "No connection" view in gap between navigation bar and view controller content.

I want to subclass UINavigationViewController and move content of view controllers inside a bit down.

Question is how to do this in right way?

My current solution is working but it is also quite hacky. I would like make it better.

```
// subclass of AGNavigationController
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    static BOOL firstTime = YES;
    if (firstTime) {
        contentView = nil;
        for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationTransitionView") class]]) {
                contentView = v;
                break;
            }
        }
        firstTime = NO;
        origFrame = contentView.frame;
        noConnectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y+self.navigationBar.frame.size.height, 320, 20);
    }
    [self adjustToConnection:NO withAnimation:NO];
}

-(void)adjustToConnection:(BOOL)isConnection withAnimation:(BOOL)animation {
    if (isConnection) {
        [noConnectionView removeFromSuperview];
        contentView.frame = origFrame;
    } else {
        [self.view addSubview:noConnectionView];
        contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, origFrame.origin.y+20, 320, origFrame.size.height-20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your `UIView` and set its frame to something like `(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.witdh, 40)`.

Use `[self.view addSubview:myView];` to add the view to your `UIViewController`.

Move your elements down in your main view, with the vertical offset set at `myView.frame.size.height`.

This is all you can get with a question like this one. If you need more help, you have to be more precise about what you tried, and what doesn't work.